# Strip Down A String at Colon

Tags: php, parsing, strip

I have a textarea where a user copies and pastes the entire message:

```
Time(UTC): 2010-02-27T21:58:20.74Z

Filesize  : 9549920 bytes

IP Address: 192.168.1.100

IP Port: 59807
```

Using PHP, how can I automate this and parse this down to 4 separate variables, like so:

```
<?php
$time = 2010-02-27T21:58:20.74Z;
$filesize = 9549920;
$ip = 192.168.1.100;
$port = 59807;
```

I can tell that each line has a colon, so I'm thinking this might have something to do with it.  I'm not sure if I would need to use substr or something.  But I'm not quite sure where to start with this?

Any help would be great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way

```
$textarea=<<<EOF
Time(UTC): 2010-02-27T21:58:20.74Z

Filesize  : 9549920 bytes

IP Address: 192.168.1.100

IP Port: 59807
EOF;

$s = explode("\n\n",$textarea);
foreach ($s as $k=>$v){
  list($a,$b) = array_map(trim,explode(": ",$v));
  # or use explode(":",$v,2) as jason suggested.
  $array[$a]=$b;
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: The first line has more than one colon. I don't think you'll get all of the value that way.

Comment: You would if you did `explode(':', $v, 2)` though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to do this when submitting a form.  And when I do so, it appears that the \n is not being submitted/passed.  I even tried $textarea = nl2br($_POST['textarea'];  Any ideas on how to make sure the \n is being passed?

Comment: you can look at the docs on nl2br :http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php. I think someone has written the opposite of nl2br. you can try that

Answer (score 2):

Is it guaranteed that each will be on its own line and in that order? Then you might be able to `explode` the entire string on `\n` and then `explode` each line on `:`. That's a quick and dirty approach. Beyond that you should go through line by line and look at the beginning of the line whether the text before the first colon matches a desired variable and, if so, parse it according to predetermined parsing rules (e.g. drop 'bytes' from the filesize value).

Comment: Ok, ghostdog gave you actual code describing my first solution.